# Append new column to df from list using python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, append

I have list `lst = ['vk.com', 'facebook.com', 'avito.ru', 'twitter.com']`
and I want to add it to this `df`:

```
date    id  request
2016-06-17 09:26:18 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 09:38:18 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 10:13:44 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 10:19:24 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
```

I try `df.append`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `length` of list is same as length of `df` use:

```
lst = ['vk.com', 'facebook.com', 'avito.ru', 'twitter.com']
df['new'] = lst

print (df)
                  date                    id       request           new
0  2016-06-17 09:26:18  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1        vk.com
1  2016-06-17 09:38:18  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1  facebook.com
2  2016-06-17 10:13:44  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1      avito.ru
3  2016-06-17 10:19:24  yans.bouts@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   twitter.com
```